# How to specify template type of inherited class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

Consider a generic collection:

```
/**
 * A collection of items of the same type
 * @template TSingleItem
 * */
class ItemsCollection {
    /** @type {TSingleItem[]} **/
    get items() {
        return [createSingleItem()];
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new item based on the implementation type
     * @param {string} param
     * @returns {TSingleItem}
     */
    createSingleItem(param) {
        throw new Error("Pure virtual method call!");
    }
}
```

Now we implement it as:

```
class Item {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Items extends ItemsCollection {
    createSingleItem(param) {
        return new Item(param);
    }
}
```

How do I tell JSDoc to assume that `items` on that inherited class is `Item[]` not `TSingleItem[]`?

I tried this above the class:

```
/**
 * @extends {ItemsCollection<Item>}
 * */
class Items extends ItemsCollection
```

That didn't help in visual studio at least. What's the correct syntax? Bonus points if it works with Visual Studio intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the correct code, as also seen [in this nice tutorial](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types#inheritance-of-generic-types):

```
/**
 * @extends {ItemsCollection<Item>}
 * */
class Items extends ItemsCollection
```

It does also work in Visual Studio 2017, just took a while to catch on. I'm leaving this Q&A instead of deleting because it wasn't exactly obvious or easy to google to confirm it.